# Is it possible to have a custom chapters file for each link/file in a playlist file in MPV?

Tags: playlist, mpv

I would like to load a playlist file that contains YouTube URLs in MPV. Like this:

`playlists.txt`

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cQJ0MMses
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s22eJ1eVLTU
```

And one or multiple chapters file:

`chapters.txt`

```
;FFMETADATA1

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/60
START=0
END=300
title=Introduction

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/60
START=300
END=6000
title=Rest of the video
```

Playing the playlist like this

`mpv --playlist=playlist.txt --chapters-file=chapters.txt`

The same chapters are shown for both videos. Is it possible to have different chapters for each video in the playlist?